# share internet connection using pointopoint method

Tags: internet

I'm trying to share internet connection between two host using ethernet device and using pointopoint method but havent yet get any proper response,
Here is the chronology:

setting ip :

host a

```
ifconfig eth0 10.0.1.1 pointopoint 10.0.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.255
```

host b

```
ifconfig eth0 10.0.1.2 pointopoint 10.0.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.255
```

setting router(host A):

from host a, which host a had set `ip_forward` to '1' (`sysctl` and `/proc/net/ipv4/`)

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
```

and on host b I've done on cli

```
route add default dev eth0
```

with `/etc/resolv.conf` contain

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

when pinging google the response like this  :

```
PING google.com (209.85.231.104) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.1.2 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.1.2 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

oh my? where is my exactly fault ?

thanks in advance guys :)

Comment: When you ping Google which host are you pinging from? On host A, what interface is your internet connection on?

Comment: the internet connection interface is ppp0.. and 'route add default gw 10.0.1.2' havent yet make this issue solves... any idea ?

Comment: ah im pinging google.com from host B(10.0.1.2)

Comment: Can you ping google from host A? Can host A and host B ping each other? Also, make sure you do **not** configure your interfaces in pointopoint mode.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use pointopoint.

Secondly, your route on Host B should be:

```
route add default gw 10.0.1.2
```

You want to set your `iptables` rule to the following:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
```

If you can provide more information I'll expand this answer to help you better.